# Appear on hover

Tags: html, css, hover, opacity, visible

The content on my website should be hidden and only when you hover inside the viewport of the browser the content should appear. The logo on the top left corner should always be visible and always be clickable.

That means when you hover outside the viewport the opacity of the content is set to 0. When you hover over inside the viewport the opacity is set to 1.

I placed my content inside a div with the class .content like this:

```
<div class="content">My content</div>
```

```
.content { 
  opacity: 0; 
  transition: .5s; 
}
.content:hover { 
  opacity: 1; 
}
```

It works perfectly.

I also added a text logo with a link that should take the visitor always back to the homepage on the top left.

```
<a class="logo" href="#">Logo</a>
```

```
.logo {position: fixed; top: 10px; left: 10px;}
```

The issue now is when you hover over the text logo the content disappears. I want the content to be visible even when you hover over the text logo.

```css
.content { 
  opacity: 0; 
  transition: .5s; 
}
.content:hover { 
  opacity: 1; 
}
.logo {
  position: fixed; 
  top: 10px; 
  left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">My content</div>

<a class="logo" href="#">Logo</a>
```

Can someone please help me find a solution?

I hope I explained my issue well enough. If you have any questions feel free to ask.

Thank you a lot for your time and efforts.

Best regards

Comment: What if a user doesn't have a mouse?

Comment: You mean Touch devices for example? I would turn of the opacity hover-effect on smaller screen sizes. Do you think media queries aren't enough in this case?